# Obter paths de URL

Tags: javascript, angularjs, url

A API está estruturada algo semelhante a `http://localhost:8181/api/collections/{id}`, minha dúvida é: Certas vezes eu preciso obter esse *{id}* e estou fazendo um replace. 
Existe alguma forma de configurar essa url para ambientes de produção, homolog e localhost para não ter que trocar toda a hora? E existe um jeito melhor de obter esse *{id}*?

A maneira que pego esse *{id}*:

```
var oknokdev = "http://localhost:8181/";
$scope.visualizar = function (id) {
        id = id.replace(oknokdev + "api/veiculos/", "");
        window.location.href = "/#/info/" + id;
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma outra forma de se pegar o id é utilizando split.

De uma maneira bem simples, utilizando angular:

```
//http://localhost:8181/api/collections/{id}
angular.module("APP",[],function($locationProvider){
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
});

function MainController($location){
    var id = $location.path().split("/")[3]||"0";    //path retorna /api/collections/{id}, e o array retorna: ["","api","collections","id",""]
    console.log(id);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Tente adaptar desta forma:

```
$scope.visualizar = function (id, host){
    var r = null;
    if(typeof(host) != undefined){
        r = new RegExp(host+'/api/[^/]+/(.+)');
    }else{
        r = new RegExp('https?://[^/]+/api/[^/]+/(.+)');
    }

    id = id.replace(r, '$1');
    window.location.href = "/#/info/" + id;
};
```

Desta forma de você pode especificar o `host` através do segundo parâmetro, ou simplesmente não passar e deixar ele tentar identificar.

Comment: Qualquer duvida sobre como isto funciona, comente que eu edito.

Answer (score 0):

Existe **n** maneiras, a melhor que eu considero, com certeza, é virtualizando o host do seu site (vhost) e criar uma  constante para em cada ambiente virtualizado,  mantendo a saída da constante por padrão para produção (editando o arquivo (no linux): `/etc/apache2/sites-available/seusite.conf` e colocando ele na lista com o comando: `a2ensite seusite.conf`, no Windows (xampp), basta editar o arquivo: `C:/xampp/apache/config/extra/httpd-vhosts.config` e restartar o apache.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName seusite.local
        ServerAlias www.seusite.local
        ServerAlias seusite_outronome.local
        #para xampp windows: DocumentRoot C:/xampp/htdocs/seuprojeto/
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/seuprojeto/ 
        
        #--->desenvolvimento
        SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "development"
    
        #--->homologação
        #SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "staging"

        #--->testes
        #SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "testing"
       
        #--->produção 
        #SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "production"

    <Directory />
            DirectoryIndex index.php
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
     </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Lembrando de habilitar seu navegador, basta colocar o IP na sequência para cada host virtualizado no Windows

```
%systemroot%\windows32\drivers\etc\hosts
```

No Ubuntu linux:

```
/etc/hosts
```

E editar os caminhos:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   seusite.local
127.0.2.1   seusite2.local
127.0.3.1   seusite3.local
```

***Obs:*** Estes endereços devem ser acessados no navegador com http://seusite.local, se vc digitar só seusite.local não vai rolar.
Então você cria um arquivo na sua pasta config, chamado: **application.ini**. Dentro dele coloque as variáveis para cada ambiente:

```
[production]
;configurações comum a todos 
appnamespace = "Application"
adapter = "PDO_Mysql"
driver_options = "SET NAMES UTF8"
[development : production]
;aqui vem configurações de desenvolvimento

username = "root"
password = "senha"
dbname = "banco_local"
host = "localhost"
site = "http://www.seusite.com.br"

[testing : production]
;aqui vem configurações de testes

username = "root"
password = "senha"
dbname = "banco_testing"
host = "localhost"
site = "http://eusite.testing.local"

[staging : production]
;aqui vem configurações de homologação

username = "root"
password = "senha"
dbname = "banco_staging"
host = "localhost"
site = "http://homolog.seusite.com.br"

[development : production]
;aqui vem configurações de produção

username = "root"
password = "senha"
dbname = "banco_production"
host = "localhost"
site = "http://seusite.local"
```

Então você carrega seu arquivo no seu projeto:

```
$application = parse_ini_file('config/application.ini');
defined('APPLICATION_ENV')
    || define('APPLICATION_ENV', (getenv('APPLICATION_ENV') ? getenv('APPLICATION_ENV') : 'production'));

define("DATABASE_SERVER", $application['host']);
define("DATABASE_USER", $application['username']);
define("DATABASE_PASS", $application['password']);
define("DATABASE_DB", $application['dbname']);
define("URL_SITE", $application['site']);
```

Mais informações aqui:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-file.php
E aqui:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.getenv.php

Se você usa algum controlador de versão como git ou svn, você pode criar o mesmo arquivo como `application.ini.template` e colocá-lo no versionamento, no caso do git, basta criar um .gitignore na raiz com o caminho: `/config/application.ini` e no svn acredito que seja .cvsignore.

No caso você poderia fazer algo assim, no PHP:

```
$bool = $_POST['redirect'];
if ($bool) {
echo json_encode(array('url'=>URL_SITE)); die();
}
```

Agora basta chamar no seu Controller do AngularJS, lembrando que é preciso ter a biblioteca do jQuery na sua view:

```
$scope.redirectUrl = function(strUrl) {
    $.post('houte.php',{redirect:true},function(data) {
           var host    = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
           var reg_exp = new RegExp(host['url'] + '/api\/(.*)\/(.+)');
           var id      = strUrl.replace(reg_exp, '$2');
           window.location.href = "/#/info/" + id;
       });
 };
```

Caso a URL que está sendo passada seja do mesmo servidor, você não precisa implementar o host, é só pegar o path direto, passando sua URL:

```
angularApp.controller('SeuController', ['$scope', '$routeParams', '$location', '$http',
    function ($scope, $routeParams, $location,  $http) {

    $scope.visualizar = function(pathUrl) {
     var reg_exp = new RegExp('/api\/(.*)\/(.+)');
        $location.path(pathUrl.replace(reg_exp,  "/info/$2"));
    };
  });
]);
```